# A smartphone was purposefully dropped from a height of 10m to test its durability from external physical impact.

Tags: probability, statistics

A smartphone was purposefully dropped from a height of 10m to test its durability from external physical impact. (The smartphone 100% damaged during a drop test). It has been shown that 80% of the damages occur in the glass screen, while the other 20% occur in the battery. A number of smartphones were tested and the tests were independent. Find the probability that the first battery damage happens on the third trial or later.

I believe we're supposed to use some type of random variable formula for this, but I don't know if it's Bernoulli or geometric.

Answer (score 1):

- You can solve this without knowing the name of the random variable.
- Consider the complement event: the first battery damage happens on the first or second trial. If you find the probability of this event, you can answer the original question.
- What is the probability the first battery damage happens on the first trial? (You just need the first trial to have battery damage.)
- What is the probability the first battery damage happens on the second trial? (You just need the first trial to have screen damage, and then the second trial to have battery damage.)

Answer (score 0):

Probability of screen damage is 80% or ${4\over 5}$

Probability of battery damage is 20% or ${1\over 5}$

Probability of battery damage in $i^{th}$ trial is $ P_i = {({4\over 5})}^{i-1}\times {1\over 5} = {4^{i-1}\over 5^i} $

Hence to find probability of battery damage on 3rd trial of later we have to add $P_3+P_4+P_4+{\cdots}+P_{\infty}$

$$P={4^{2}\over 5^3}+{4^{3}\over 5^4}+{4^{4}\over 5^5}+ {\cdots}$$
$$P={4^{2}\over 5^3}\times {1\over {1-{4\over 5}}} $$
$$P={4^{2}\over 5^2}$$
$$P={16\over 25}$$